# set_conditional_value for date column in phpgrid

Tags: php, date, jqgrid

I have this "Date" column on my grid, but because it has a datetime datatype, I only want to show the date and remove the time. So, I'm using:

```
$dg -> set_col_date("Date", "Y-m-d", "Y-m-d", "yy-mm-dd");
```

But, I also need the set_conditional_value to a specified Date column

//1st try

```
$dg->set_conditional_value("Date", "=='2013-07-02'", array("TCellValue"=>"TOTAL"));
```

//2nd try

```
$dg->set_conditional_value("Date", "=='2013-07-02 00:00:00.000'", array("TCellValue"=>"TOTAL"));
```

Both didn't work unless I throw out the set_col_date and use the 2nd try set_conditional_value.

I need both of the function to run. How should this work?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried set_col_format or set_col_property?

http://phpgrid.com/documentation/set_col_format/

http://phpgrid.com/documentation/set_col_property/

Last resort, use CSS3 text-overflow to hide characters: 
[Hide last character in string with pure css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150580/hide-last-character-in-string-with-pure-css)