# Hide last character in string with pure css

Tags: css

Is it possible to remove or simply hide the very last character in a string in pure css?

When I search for this all I find is javascript / jQuery solutions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change last letter color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441742/change-last-letter-color)

Comment: You can add a span tag between it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use CSS3 **`text-overflow`**.

([More information about `text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow))

[**Live demo on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/z47A7/)

---

**CSS:**

```
#txt{
    position:relative;
    padding:7px;
    text-align:justify;
    background:#e7e7e7;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**Working in:** (latest versions)

- firefox
- chrome
- opera
- ie ( does not matter :D )

Comment: you can add `width` to `#txt` too ;)

Comment: This didn't work for me, so I have other solution in case someone will come across of this question. I have created :after pseudoelement and added this css to it: `content: "";
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 right: 5px;
 top: 4px;
 background-color: red;
 width: 10px;
 height: 1em;`. You might need to adjust the positioning and replacing the `red` with your background color.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, that's not possible using pure CSS; there's a ::first-letter selector, but no ::last-letter. Instead, you could use tags to set off the last letter from the rest of the text.